# Syncfusion edit grid with timezone issue

Tags: .net-core, grid, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

Whenever I edit inline and save below Syncfusion EJ2 dot net core razor page code, time is getting sybstracted by 5:30 timezone offset as Server sends UTC time and my browser is in India time (+5:30). How to fix this in grid?

```
        <ejs-grid id="UserGrid" load="onLoad" height="500" actionComplete="actionComplete" allowSorting="true" actionBegin="actionBegin" allowPaging="true" actionFailure="onActionFailure" toolbar="toolbarItems" allowResizing="true" autoFit="true" allowTextWrap="true">
            <e-grid-editsettings allowEditing="true" mode="Normal"></e-grid-editsettings>
            <e-data-manager url="/church/member-dob?handler=DataSource" updateUrl="/church/member-dob?handler=Update" adaptor="UrlAdaptor"></e-data-manager>
            <e-grid-pagesettings pageSize="50"></e-grid-pagesettings>
            <e-grid-columns>
                <e-grid-column field="PersonId" width="10" visible="false" headerText="PersonId" isPrimaryKey="true"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="PersonId2" allowEditing="false" width="100" headerText="PID"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="FamId2" allowEditing="false" width="100" headerText="FID"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="FamName" allowEditing="false" width="200" headerText="Family"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="PersonDom" width="200" editType="datepickeredit" edit="@(new { @params = new { format = "dd/MM/yyyy" } })"  headerText="DOM(dd/MM/yyyy)"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="PersonName" headerText="Person"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="PersonEmail" headerText="Email"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="PersonPh" headerText="Phone"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="MemberUsername" headerText="username"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="MemberPassword" headerText="password"></e-grid-column>
            </e-grid-columns>
        </ejs-grid>
```